# Homomorphism of Rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove this one?
Let $f: R \longrightarrow S$ be a homomorphism of rings $R$ and $S$. If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $S$, then $f^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal iseal of $R$.

Comment: First off, I think you need to tell us exactly what you mean by "ring" (and possibly homomorphism). There are, unfortunately, several distinct conventions for what that word entails.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is not correct. Consider the ring homomorphism $f : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q$ given by $f(x) = x$.

Then, $\{0\}$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Q$ but its preimage $\{0\}$ is not maximal in $\Bbb Z$.

---

What you have written is true if $f$ is onto. (At least with the convention that $R$ and $S$ are commutative with unity and $f$ maps $1_R$ to $1_S$.) An answer to that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049344/427810).